# Is it better to write a novel with contractions?

Tags: creative-writing

In a subjective omniscient PoV, is it better to use contractions for the narrator’s voice, or to avoid them for a more formal and distinctive tone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing that is "better" in general in writing. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want your narrator to appear impartial, objective and detached, narrate in unobtrusive standard English.

If you want your narrator to have character, to appear partial to the events, to be potentially untrustwrothy and so on, write in a style that is more oral and fitting to that character.

Both approaches can and have been employed to great effect.